Resources Pushing An Agent From Station to Station
I am building a model of a production line where workers push the items from station to station. The items are on a monorail, so they act like they are on a conveyor, but need a worker to move them.
I tried using paths and nodes to act as the monorail and stations (uzing seize, moveTo, Delay, Release blocks) which worked great until it came to queueing. The agents would have no where to go if the station was full.
I am new to Anylogic and anything helps. Thank you!

just let them move on the conveyor but put seize-release blocks around it (seizing a worker)? Worth a try
